# Add AJAX response data to a Div

Tags: javascript, get, onclick

Having trouble with following code, it gets the data that I want but it won't append to the div #playercontent instead it appears in a console when I run it.

WORKING WITH PHP, Slim, HTML, JSON. To clear it up.

> ```
> $(document).ready(function(){
>
>
> $.ajax({
> type: 'GET',
> dataType: "json",
> url: "db.php/players", 
> success: showResponse, 
> error: showError
> });
>
> });
>
>
>
>
> console.debug("error");
>
> function showResponse(responseData){
>
>   $("#get1").click(function getPlayers(responseData) {
>   console.log('Image is clicked');
>   console.log(responseData);
>     $.each(responseData.player, function(index, player){
>       console.log(' is ');
>         $("#playercontent").append(" </br>Player Position:" +player.PlayerPosition+"</br> Full Name:" +player.PlayerName+ " "+player.PlayerLastName+" </br>Team Name:" +player.TeamName);
>             // $("#playercontent").append("</li>");
>         console.log('Data should output');
>     });
>   });
>
> console.log(responseData);
>     }
>     console.debug("hello");
>
> function showError(){
> alert("Sorry, but something went wrong. Fix it!!!!")
> }
> ```

Comment: Please do not spam with tags. Your question is not related neither with `Slim` nor `PHP`.

Comment: Thanks for your help mate @MarcinOrlowski

Comment: Try moving function `showResponse` inside the  `$(document).ready(function(){...}`. We need to make sure element `playercontent` exists before the function `showResponse` is defined.

Answer (score 0):

The code to append the data to the `#playercontent` div is within an onclick event handler that's within your AJAX request's success handler. i.e. it's not going to run because the click will never happen as you're within an `.ajax` success callback. Try moving the code that iterates over the `responseData` outside of the onclick handler so that it is directly in the `showResponse` function.

Also `console.debug("error");` and `console.debug("hello");` messages will display every page request and before the `.ajax` call happens…